# Why can I pass a string parameter like this? Is this style safe?

Tags: c++, string

I am passing two strings as one parameter in XCode and using c++. I tried this in XCode and it works. But is this safe on all platforms?

```
#include <iostream>

void log_person(const char* name_and_number){
    printf("name and number : %s.\n", name_and_number);
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    log_person("jim" "123456789");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a single string. This

```
"Foo" "Bar"
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
"FooBar"
```

so your call is the same as

```
log_person("jim123456789");
```

This is standard C++ and so is "safe" on any conforming implementation. See *2.14.5/13* in the C++11 standard:

> **2.14.5 String literals**
>
> ...
>
> <sup>13</sup>  In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated....

Comment: I am confused.do you mean the complier treats this style as a single string?

Comment: @nosources Yes, exactly. Because the language specifies it, and the compiler implements the language.

Comment: thanks for your answer.could you tell me where can i find more information about this specification?

Comment: @nosources The C++ standard. I added a quote.

Comment: I have found that in the book with your help, I am wondering how did you find that, have you read the whole book?

Comment: @nosources To be honest, I don't remember. I just knew it somehow, and usually I know where to look things up in the standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77590/discussion-between-nosources-and-juanchopanza).